# How can I conditionally format textbox border on continuous form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I have a continuous form, and I'd like to change certain properties of a 'cell', like border colour, based on values in another cell. I haven't found a way to do this in VBA, because it's a continuous form and changing the properties directly in VBA changes it for all records, not just the one I'm on. I assume I have to use some form of conditional formatting, but the conditional formatting GUI only allows me to set background colour, basic text formatting, and the Enabled property.

How can I set other properties on a control on a continuous form, for specific records only?

Answer (score 2):

Feeding back how I got around this problem in the end. txtFixMax is the control I wanted to give a funky border to (dependent on a value in field [ChangedToday]). It already has conditional formatting to change the background colour. 
I created a second control, txtFixMaxOverlay, made it into a small square and placed it on top of the control txtFixMax.   I set the properties of txtFixMaxOverlay to remove borders, and gave it the same conditional formatting as txtFixMax, so that it was invisible to the eye (but the Visible property = true).  Then I gave it additional condition, the first one on the list, based on [ChangedToday], to change its background colour.

The effect isn't a border (although with a lot of tedious positioning of 4 controls I could have done this to give a border effect), but it does give me an extra element to visually change. The effect is:
[image: this]

Comment: Ack, am I allowed/supposed to accept my own answer? O.o

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to accept your own answer, if you consider it to be the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Use background or text color.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821010.aspx - there is only `BackColor` and `ForeColor`.

Comment: Thanks, Andre. I am hoping that someone has found some clever workaround though.. I've experimented with overlaying textboxes and all sorts, but not hit on anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can... just not with the built-in conditional formatting functionality.  **Use the Paint event** of the Form's Detail section.  There are still various limitations, but at the least you can set more properties than just the background and foreground colors.

Example:

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
  If Me.IndicatorColumn.Value = "Critical" Then
    Detail.BackColor = RGB(255,0,0)
    Detail.AlternateBackColor = Detail.BackColor
    Me.AnotherColumn.BorderStyle = 7 'Dash Dot Dot
    Me.AnotherColumn.BorderColor = vbMagenta
  Else
    Detail.BackColor = vbWhite
    Detail.AlternateBackColor = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    Me.AnotherColumn.BorderStyle = 0 'Transparent
    Me.AnotherColumn.BorderColor = vbWhite
  End If
End Sub
```

See [TextBox.BorderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/textbox-borderstyle-property-access).